# jQuery: Show and hide menu

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, show, preventdefault

I have this code:

```
$('.skaftetopmenu-li > a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var subid = $(this.parentNode).attr('id');
   if (subid !="forsidemenu"){
      var str = $('#submenu-content-'+subid).html();
      if ($.trim(str) == ""){
         $('.submenu-content', this.parentNode).load('http://' + skafte.base_url + '/inc/top-menu-subs/'+subid+'_submenu.html');
      }

   }
});
```

This disables the top links. And loads the child elements when pressed. However I can only get the child elements to show but I can't get them to dissapear when I press the toplink again or press another.

---

EDIT:

Heres af piece of the HTML of the topmenu:

```
<div id="header-menu">
   <ul id="mainmenu" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <li class="skaftetopmenu-li" id="forsidemenu" >
         <a href="http://<?php echo DOMAIN?>/">Forside</a>
      </li>
      <li class="skaftetopmenu-li" id="priser">
         <a href="http://<?php echo DOMAIN?>/priser.php">Priser &amp; Sortiment</a>
         <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-priser"></div>
      </li>
  <li class="skaftetopmenu-li" id="onlinebestilling">
     <a href="http://<?php echo DOMAIN?>/bestil.php">Onlinebestilling</a>
         <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-onlinebestilling"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="skaftetopmenu-li" id="levering-top">
     <a href="http://<?php echo DOMAIN?>/levering-fadoel.php">Fad&oslash;l til Fest</a>
     <div class="submenu-content" id="submenu-content-levering"></div>
  </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The above div (submenu-content-priser) loads the file /inc/top-menu-subs/priser_submenu.html, which looks like this:

```
<ul class="submenu-item-ul">
   <li class="li-content">
      <div class="menucontent">
         <div>
            <b>Priser på Sodavand & Vand mm.</b>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="http://skafte.dk/priser.php?moms=1">Kassevarer med moms</a></li>
               <li><a href="http://skafte.dk/priser.php?moms=0">Kassevarer uden moms</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="last">
            <b>Priser på Fadøl</b>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="http://skafte.dk/priser-fadoel.php">Fad&oslash;l, leje & udstyr til fest</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have the sub-menu contents pre-loaded in the document.ready, and then just show then in the click event u wrote, and hide them in the below event.

You may try this:

```
$('body').click(function(evt){
   if(evt.target.id == "menu_content")
      return;

   $('#menu_content').hide();
});
```

You have to change "menu_content" with the ID of the sub-menu div.

Comment: Thanks, but the ID is different from sub to sub. See the attached HTML. So how do I incorporate this in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set all the child elements of the menu to hidden, and then show the one that's selected.

For instance, add something like this in the click function:

```
$('.submenu-content').hide();
$(this).find('.submenu-content').show()
```

(Hard to tell without some HTML to go with it.)

Comment: I have attached some HTML now, will try out your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Display or hide the matched elements.

**toggle**

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I know about the toggle function and I have tried to use it, but I can't figure out how to implement it in the code